# CQL Composite primary key query for getting data

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have column family that have two primary keys

```
"CREATE TABLE compositkeys(user_name varchar," +
                                            "user_id int,"+
                                            "name varchar," +
                                            "gender varchar," +
                                            "PRIMARY KEY (user_name,user_id)" +


                        ")";
```

I have created this in Java now i inserted 6 rows with on one user_name(sunil) primarykey with different id now when I try to retrieve all the value in sunil primary key it gives me only one detail

```
String qry = "select * from compositkeys where user_name = 'sunil' order by user_id";
            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            //smt.executeUpdate(qry);

            ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(qry);
            //rs.get
            int r = rs.getRow();
            System.out.println(r);
            ResultSetMetaData rm = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rm.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println(columnCount);
            for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++)
            {
                String name = rm.getColumnName(i);
                 System.out.print(rm.getColumnName(i));
                 System.out.println(" = "+rs.getString(name));
                 System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
            }
```

It gives me only one output. Is there any thing wrong in query? I want all the data under the key sunil.

Comment: Try it out in cqlsh. If it doesn't work as expected, copy and paste your problem session here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single loop that loops over the columns in a returned row, but you only ask for one row (that's the rs.getRow() method).  You should put the rs.getRow() call and the following logic to write the results into an outer loop that iterates as long as getRow() doesn't return null.  This out loop is what will retrieve all of a user's ids.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this problem?